# How to use array values as Variables in big multidimensional Array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have to access to all values stored in a big multidimensional array, here's an example of print_r the array:

```
Array
(
    [Novedad] => Array
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [CUNENov] => 4545454545
                )

        )

    [Periodo] => Array
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [FechaIngreso] => 1998-12-12
                    [FechaRetiro] => 2021-11-12
                    [FechaLiquidacionInicio] => 2021-05-01
                    [FechaLiquidacionFin] => 2021-05-30
                    [TiempoLaborado] => 10829
                    [FechaGen] => 2021-05-05
                )

        )
    [Devengados] => Array
        (
            [Basico] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [DiasTrabajados] => 30
                            [SueldoTrabajado] => 1258955.00
                        )

                )
         )
)
```

The thing I want to do is extract the values from that array, I have tried this way:

```
<?php
$cunenov = $array['Novedad']['@attributes']['CUNENov'];
```

but doesn't work..
Any suggests?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apart from naming the variable `$test` in the first snippet and trying to access a variable named `$array` in the second one, I don't see why this wouldn't work: https://3v4l.org/ZHKaU

Comment: Are you sure it's really an array, not an object?

Comment: @Barmar It looks like a `php` `print_r()` to me .. So I have no doubt it's an array --  My assumtion is he is *naming* the array `$test` in the example .. And he's *calling*  `$array['...`

Comment: Yes.. I forget that.. That are the print_r output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted you to see the "constructed" array and the outputs ..  Stand alone, this `php` works ..  Paste it into a stand alone `php` file and determine what you're doing differently to not achieve the same result.

Building out the array, and then `print_r` so you can validate it's the same structure as your array.

```
<?php

$test = Array();
$test['Novedad'] = array();
$test['Novedad']['@attributes'] = array();
$test['Novedad']['@attributes']['CUNENov'] = 4545454545;
   
print_r( $test );
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [Novedad] => Array
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [CUNENov] => 4545454545
                )

        )

)
```

Then we echo:

```
    $cunenov = $test['Novedad']['@attributes']['CUNENov'];
    echo "Value is $cunenov";
```

Yields

```
Value is 4545454545
```